# Method not found: 'Void System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterModule(System.Type)'

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

On each web project i create i got this error, any ideas?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Method not found: 'Void System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterModule(System.Type)'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterModule(System.Type)'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterModule(System.Type)'.]
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.SelectionMappingExecutionListenerModule.PreApplicationStart() +0
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Startup.PreApplicationStart() +8

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +0
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner) +72
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +335
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +28
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.RuntimeLoader.LoadRuntime() +63
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.RuntimeLoader.PreApplicationStart() +18

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method PreApplicationStart on type Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.RuntimeLoader threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +408
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +303
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +693

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method PreApplicationStart on type Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.RuntimeLoader threw an exception with the following error message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +637
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +256

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1008
```

(sorry, i have to write something else otherwise stack overflow dont let me post the question)
(again and again)

Comment: Please post the `system.web/httpModules` part of your web.config

Comment: now i'm not at work, what i can say is that Void System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterModule(System.Type) seems to target the 4.5, but my project target the 4.0 framework.
I found this post where a guy had a problem on the same point, but his project do not crash as the mine:
http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2012/12/28/rip-page-inspector-out-of-your-web-site-projects-now.aspx

Comment: Solved. There is Moles installed on the machine that conflicts to the framework 4.5.
I installed some vs updates that causes this problem.
The solution was:
- Remove the framework 4.5 components using cleanup tool
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx
- Run the vs restore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moles installed on the machine conflicted to the framework v4.5 where  installation of some VS updates could be cause of this problem.

The solution was to remove the framework 4.5 components using [.NET Framework Cleanup Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/08/28/net-framework-cleanup-tool-users-guide/), then run the VS restore.

Related: [Page Inspector causing multiple calls to `HttpApplication`: `Application_Start`](http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2012/12/28/rip-page-inspector-out-of-your-web-site-projects-now.aspx).

<sup>Source: [@Paolo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17240001/method-not-found-void-system-web-httpapplication-registermodulesystem-type/46582471#comment25081023_17240001).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in MonoFramework MDK v4.2.0 (bug [#21810](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21810)) and similar issue in v4.3.2 (bug [#33809](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33809)).

In ASP.Net MVC5, the `System.HttpApplication.RegisterModule()` which has been added in Mono Framework v5.4.0.203 (as per this [commit](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/58e0608c10c621b15fd9f396f8e46c567891b231)).